Issue with VCAP voltage
I am currently working on a board designed around the STM32H725RGV6 and have encountered issues with it being recognised by STM32CubeProgrammer as I get the message "target not found" when connecting it to a STLINK-v3-minie. With my previous experience using H7 or F7 MCUs, they get pretty warm even while idling which mine does not.
VDD is 3.3V and supplied from a LDO regulator, TPS73633. With the board fully populated except the bluetooth module, RN4871, I have verified that the MCU is receiving 3.3V through the VDD pins.
I have also checked that BOOT0 is pulled low and NRST is pulled high.
2 of the 3 VCAP pins have 2.2uF caps placed nearby and the third is connected to the other 2.
I have used a multimeter and continuity tested the majority of the pins to their adjacent pins and GND to check for shorts. None were found.
The board was assembled by JLC except for the MCU which I had to reflow myself. I had to reflow it 3 times until I was satisfied with how the joints looked. The board was also cleaned thoroughly with IPA.
I have read that I have to choose the correct power configuration in CubeIDE but I don't get how I would be able to do this without connecting the STLINK first.No code has been uploaded to the MCU yet anyways.
I realised that I have added an extra capacitor to the VDDA pins but I don't believe this would prevent the H7 from working.
Hence I have narrowed it down to the VCAP pin which had a steady output of 0.08V. I immediately believed that I had fried the MCU by reflowing it too many times so I replaced it with another one which only took 2 tries to reflow. After checking for shorts, the voltage at the VCAP pins now seems to oscillating from 0V to 0.12V slowly. I don't have access to a oscilloscope currently but my multimeter still picks up on this oscillation. I only have one more MCU on hand so I don't want to try with my last one.
Any advice is very welcome. I have attached my schematic, PCB layout and photos of the MCU's solder joints. The board is very space constrained.

enter image description here



enter image description here

First things first. Have you checked that the STM32 is at correct orientation, not rotated by 90 or 180 degrees? Which is pin 1 mark on your board, the star-alike white dot? You are not supposed to pull NRST high, it's pulled to the MISC supply so it must be present then, an there is no capacitor on NRST.

@Burglups I have used these LDOs before and they have worked without any problems. Also to answer your question about it being a gamepad, it's actually a micromouse.

@Justme pin 1 is denoted by the asterisk and the mcu is oriented correctly. Could you elaborate more on what you mean regarding the NRST pin?

Guess I should've read everything about every pin. The NRST function shouldn't be critical to my project so I'll try removing the switch and resistor and replacing it with a single capacitor to ground.

@DanielR the NRST button does no harm, it is normal. Pull up is not recommended but should do no harm. Missing capacitor causes too short reset so that may be a problem with slowly rising supplies.

@Burglups I don't think that is the first thing you should check. The MCU is missing the core supply so it will not respond to programmer for sure.

I decided to tie the BOOT0 pin to GND because I planned on uploading code via a programmer/debugger only and never planned to use the bootloader.

@Burglups Why do you ask about the resistor on BOOT0? It has no effect on the problem, whether it is tied via resistor or directly.

@Burglups the external LDO was chosen because of its 75mV dropout voltage which was necessary because the robot is being powered by a very small 1s LiPo battery. Also, I'm not planning on pushing the H7 to its limits and currently no code is running on the mcu so the LDO shouldn't be the limiting factor

@Burglups If you think there is a reason why the resistor makes a difference, then state it. Also the MCU will not consume max current it possibly can. Especially not without a program that can't be programmed because internal core voltage is missing, not the 3.3V from regulator. I see no problem with the resistor or regulator at this point.

@Justme I found this post on ST's forums https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus/why-my-stm32-doesn-t-start/ta-p/49367
At one point it details the following;
"Another possibility for Vcore generation is available with integrated SMPS. If SMPS is not implemented or not available for given STM32 (STM32L4, STM32H7), switching core power supply to SMPS option during start may render STM32 unresponsive. The workaround is to power on the chip with BOOT0=1, i.e. starting the system bootloader which relies only on linear voltage regulator, and to erase the chip."
Though I dont get it's meaning

@Justme @Burglups Thank you for your responses.
In the datasheet it states that the specific variant of STM32H725 only features an SMPS and no internal LDO, which my schematic does not fall in line with. I connected the MCU to be powered in LDO supply when I should've configured it to run in SMPS supply. The datasheet is not very clear; for future reference there is some more information in this forum post: VCAP voltage issue
